# Indexing/Performance strategies for vast amount of the same value

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing

Base information: This is in context to the indexing process of OpenStreetMap data. To simplify the question: the core information is divided into 3 main types with value "W", "R", "N" (`VARCHAR(1)`).

The table has somewhere around ~75M rows, all columns with "W" make up ~42M rows. Existing indexes are not relevant to this question.

---

Now the question itself: The indexing of the data is done via an procedure. Inside this procedure, there are some loops that do the following:

[...] SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_key = "W"; [...]

The results get looped again and the above query itself is also in a loop. This takes a lot of time and slows down the process massivly. An indexon `the_key` is obviously useless since all the values that the index might use are the same ("W"). The script itself is running with a speed that is OK, only the `SELECT`ing takes very long.

Do I

- need to create a "special" kind of index that takes this into account and makes the `SELECT` quicker? If so, which one?
- need to tune some of the server parameters (they are already tuned and the result that they deliver seem to be good. If needed, I can post them)?
- have to live with the speed and simply get more hardware to gain more power (Tim Taylor grunt *grunt*)?

Any alternatives to the above points (except rewriting it or not using it)?

Comment: What else can you optimize ? It might be the slowness comes from the sheer volume of data you process. e.g. don't do SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_key = "W" in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query could use an index if you set `work_mem` high enough to enable a bitmap index scan.  It's quite possible, however, that the optimizer still won't choose to use it.  Altogether, there isn't much to optimize about this.  It looks like the surrounding looping code is in need of improvement.

Comment: +1. If over half the rows match the `the_key = 'W'` condition, then the planner will probably choose a table scan anyway, won't it? The key is to avoid looping over that resultset more than once.

Answer (score 1):

First you say:

> The table has somewhere around ~75M
>   rows, all columns with "W" make up
>   ~42M rows.

Then you say that you do

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_key = "W";
```

several times in a loop and expect it to perform? It is impossible - no indexing would speed up this query - it has to return 42M rows - more than half. If you refuse to rewrite this indexing procedure to avoid querying this more than once then it is just [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) worthy.

Comment: I don't expcet any magic or something. Maybe there are "hidden gems" that could have helped, I'm always hoping for something like that ;). I just wanted verification that this is the fault of the author of the script.  
Anyway +1 for subtle sarcasm^^